# ASP Classic reading XML Feed

Tags: xml, asp-classic, xml-parsing

I am having trouble reading the following feed. http://www.whatsonincapetown.com/feed/

my code is as follows:

```
<%

TheFeed = "http://www.whatsonincapetown.com/feed/"

Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDOM.async = False
xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlDOM.Load("TheFeed")

Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("rss[1]/channel/item") 

myCount = 0
response.write "Getting Cape Town News Feed."
For Each itemAttrib In itemList
    myCount = myCount + 1
    response.write (myCount)
    newsSubject =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("title").text
    newsExtract =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("description").text
    newsDate =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("pubDate").text
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=newsSubject%></td>
        <td><%=newsDate%></td>
        <td><%=newsExtract%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
Next

Set xmlDOM = Nothing
Set itemList = Nothing

%>
```

Anyone have any idea why it is not able to parse the feed, and is not giving any form of error.

Comment: Have you tried anything to debug this? Like, do you get the response.write in the loop at all?

Comment: I fail to see the count at all, I have tried

rss/channel/item  - 

rss[1]/channel/item  -

/channel/item  -

item - 

None of these seem's to work. I am on IIS 7, the code should have worked in theory.

Comment: I can only think it is some sort of addressing problem, looking for any example of code that would work with that feed, since with other feed's it has worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and change

```
xmlDOM.Load("TheFeed")
```

to

```
xmlDOM.Load(TheFeed)
```

because TheFeed is a variable, not a string :-)

Comment: because I am an idiot. Thanks. Also seems I do not need to say which node element ala [].

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's an asp script to read RSS feeds here.  The comments are in Danish but that shouldn't be a problem if you understand VBS.

https://web.archive.org/web/20050517002557/http://www.html.dk/scripts/asp/00020/

However IMO the best way to parse XML with Classic ASP is to use an XSL Stylesheet.  Your ASP code would look like this.

```
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
  xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
  xml.async = false
  xml.validateOnParse = false
  xml.load("http://yourfeed")
  set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
  xsl.load(Server.Mappath("yourstylesheet.xsl"))
  Response.Write(xml.transformNode(xsl))
  set xsl = nothing
  set xml = nothing
```

You should be able to find a ready made rss reader xsl document online somewhere